# Convert or extract Seurat object as the input of FateID

Tags: single-cell

I am currently using Seurat to do the scRNA-seq clustering analysis. After this, I am planning to use FateID to do the downstream analysis, could someone teach me how to convert or extract a Seurat object as the input for FateID?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`Seurat` objects have various `slot`s where different types and forms of data are stored. For `FateID` you would need an expression matrix (with cells as columns and genes as rows) and this can be extracted via:

```
seurat_object@assays$RNA@data
```

Here `RNA` is the assay (you can have multiple assays per sample, RNA, protein, ...) and `data` is normalized data. You can extract counts or scaled data instead.

If you are using `Seurat v2`, drop the `@assays$RNA` part.

Comment: Dear haci, thx, I will try.

Comment: Thank you @haci, I have figured out it by myself.